# Use DreamFactory SQL with SSL Connection

Tags: php, ssl, curl

Just installed DreamFactory on a server and have it connecting correctly to the database. When trying to send a cURL request, I'm receiving this error:

> curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to [api.domain.net].

I'm not exactly sure where to start to get this to work with an SSL connection to the database. Any help would be incredible at this point because searching this issue isn't helping much.

Answer (score 0):

Are you forcing SSL3? Since [DreamFactory docs](https://github.com/dreamfactorysoftware/dsp-core/wiki/REST-API-Authentication#using-ssl-with-our-api-requires-ssl3) say "Using SSL with our API requires SSL3" you may need to use the `-3` or `--sslv3` cURL options, as indicated on [the cURL man page](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html). The [DreamFactory docs page of cURL examples](https://github.com/dreamfactorysoftware/dsp-core/wiki/cURL-Examples) uses the `-3` option repeatedly. You will need to ensure that SSLv3 support is enabled in your web server of choice, as well.

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26187372/php-curl-error-unknown-ssl-protocol-error-in-connection-to) indicates the cURL error message "Unknown SSL protocol error" can be caused by using the wrong SSL/TLS protocol version, so the above is the most likely resolution given the details provided.

You will also need to ensure you've properly installed and enabled your SSL cert. If you deployed DreamFactory using Bitnami, you may want to review [their documentation on enabling SSL](https://wiki.bitnami.com/Components/Apache#How_to_enable_HTTPS_support_with_SSL_certificates). If you installed DreamFactory manually, you will need to consult documentation for your particular environment. Just visiting `https://[api.domain.net]` in a modern browser should give you a good indication of whether or not your cert is properly installed and enabled. Your browser will also report which version of SSL is being used.

Since your question is not specific and does not provide details on your setup, I cannot provide a more concrete answer. If you can edit to provide basic information, the community may provide a better response.